# Is Windows using the OBEX Object Push profile to send a file to android smartphone?

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, bluez, obexftp

I am able to send a file from Windows PC to my Android smartphone via Bluetooth. But I am currently unable to do the same in linux using `obexftp`. I am now doubtful, what profile does Windows 7 used to transmit the file to Android via bluetooth?

Comment: Yes, Windows uses Object Push Profile. That is what OPP must do. FTP is for a little bit other things. By the way, I am not so familiar with obexftp tool you referred to by if you can changes its UUID from FTP to OPP it will receive the file from your Windows PC because Push command is absolutely identical for both profiles. You can think about OPP as about subset (with just 2 or 2 commands) of FTP (which has full commands set).

Comment: My last tinkerings on this matter revealed that the latest `bluez` changes has introduced so much stuff in the `linux` bluetooth landscape that existing higher level apps are having difficulty catching up. For example, this `dbus` thing is one. Another one is the deprecation of previously working bluetooth tools like `sdpd` daemon and many others. Yet, I also find them being integrated in the latest `bluez` in bits and pieces work-in-progress it felt like.

Comment: OPP, FTP, SynML, SPP and any other high-level sevrices do not depend on low-level implementation. As well as dbus still somewere outside Bluetooth stack. So this must not change anything in Bluetooth. bluez still implements standard Bluetooth protocol stack above PC bus level (USB, Serial, PCMCI or any other).